# PsychoPy has stopped producing all data files

Tags: python, psychopy, autosave

Any time I run any experiment, including the demos included with PsychoPy, the only data that appears is the log file. I haven't changed anything, I restarted my computer, and the experiments were all running fine previously.

I don't get an error message or any indication that anything is wrong (no crashes), but nothing appears. I have checked the experimental settings and trials loop dialogue, although this shouldn't matter, since the demos are having the same problem. Again, these are independent experiment files in different directories that previously saved .csv, .xls., etc. without issue.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening? Is there a problem with a Python module that PsychoPy relies on? I'm running OSX with the latest version of PsychoPy.

Comment: I'd suggest taking this to discourse.psychopy.org This isn't really a StackOverflow coding question, and there might need to be a bit of to-and-fro discussion on this.

Comment: Thanks, I have done and hope someone answers. I am totally baffled and my project is in limbo until I've got it sorted.